# Disable Torsocks DNS feature

Tags: dns, npm, tor, torsocks

How can I stop torsocks from making DNS queries?

Instead I want to make normal DNS queries. I know that will mean a DNS leak, but I need it.

Because for some reason when I do `torsocks npm login` it returns a socket hang up error, which I remember I fixed it, back in the day, by blocking those DNS queries.

Any ideas are welcome.

EDIT:
Using this approach:

`tordns_enable = false`
in the conf file

Returns me this, when running the command shown above:

`ERROR: npm is setuid. torsocks will not work on a setuid executable.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you edit your `torsocks.conf` file and add a line:

```
tordns_enable = false
```

That should disable DNS resolution over Tor and instead use the computer's regular DNS resolvers.

Comment: I tried that before and didn't work. It says: `ERROR: npm is setuid. torsocks will not work on a setuid executable.`. Question updated.

Comment: Since torsocks won't work with setuid, try removing that attribute from the file:  `sudo chmod a-s /path/to/npm`.  Note, if npm links to something, you might need to run chmod on the target of the link too.

Comment: No longer works, `Config file contains unknown value: tordns_enable = false`